# check on terminal for XAMPP apache and mysql service has started or not

Tags: shell, terminal, xampp

I need to  check weather the required service is up on XAMPP on shell terminal for automation purpose.

I tried `service` cmd but service is not listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xampp start/stop script, two parts are related with startappache and startmysql, both start with the status check.

```
    "startapache")
            if $XAMPP_ROOT/share/xampp/testrun $XAMPP_ROOT/logs/httpd.pid httpd
            then
                    $de && echo "XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache läuft bereits."
                    $de || echo "XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is already running."
            fi

    "startmysql")
            if $XAMPP_ROOT/share/xampp/testrun $XAMPP_ROOT/var/mysql/`/bin/hostname`.pid mysqld
            then
                    $de && echo "XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL läuft bereits."
                    $de || echo "XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is already running."
            fi
```

So the command `$XAMPP_ROOT/share/xampp/testrun` is used to check weather the required service is up on XAMPP.

Another way, check by process name directly.

```
ps -ef |grep xampp
```

If you need check xampp apache services:

```
ps -ef |grep xampp|grep httpd
```

If you need check xampp mysql services:

```
ps -ef |grep xampp |grep mysql
```